# Static and non-static synchronization, why the output results differ?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronization, non-static

Why is there a difference in output? I have 2 cases:

1. In first case I use static functions `f1` and `f2`:

   ```java
   public static synchronized void f1() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           System.out.print("A");
   }

   public static synchronized void f2() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           System.out.print("B");
   }
   ```

   Here is my main method body:

   ```java
   Thread t1 = new Thread(
           new Runnable(){public void run(){f1();}}
   );

   Thread t2 = new Thread(
           new Runnable(){public void run(){f2();}}
   );
   t1.start();
   t2.start();
   ```

   the output is:

   ```
   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
   ```
2. In the second case `f1` and `f2` are not static:

   ```java
   public synchronized void f1() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           System.out.print("A");
   }

   public synchronized void f2() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           System.out.print("B");
   }
   ```

   the output is so messy:

   ```
   AAABABABBBBAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAA
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static synchronized functions synchronize on the class while non-static synchronized functions synchronize on the instance.

This means that when the functions are static they block each other while when they're not (and use different instances) they don't.

If your class is called `MyClass` then:

```
public static synchronized foo() {...}
```

Is similar to:

```
public static foo() {
    synchronized (MyClass.class) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

While :

```
public synchronized foo() {...}
```

Is similar to:

```
public foo() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Generally you want to specify what you're synchronizing on (what resource do you want to hold exclusively?) and avoid using the implicit synchronization on the class/instance because of this reason exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`static` also applies a lock at the class ([JLS-8.4.3.6. `synchronized` Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6) says, in part, *for a class (`static`) method, the monitor associated with the `Class` object for the method's class is used. For an instance method, the monitor associated with `this` (the object for which the method was invoked) is used*). In your case, you could remove the `static` from the method(s) and `synchronize` on `System.out`. Something like

```
public void f1() {
    synchronized (System.out) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("A");
        }
    }
}   

public void f2() {
    synchronized (System.out) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("B");
        }
    }
}
```

which will force the threads to acquire a lock on `System.out` before writing.